# Chrome extension that can add dark mode in Google Documents

Tags: chrome, google-apps, dark-theme

I'm looking for a Chrome extension that can add dark mode in Google Documents.

---

What I unsuccessfully tried so far:

1. Chrome's native dark mode:  doesn't apply dark mode on the document itself.
2. Dark Reader Chrome extension: make the document impossible to read.
3. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-dark-mode/lgjhepbpjcmfmjlpkkdjlbgomamkgonb?hl=en doesn't apply dark mode on the document itself:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One workaround if one can edit the doc: using "pageless"  option in GDoc introduced in 2022.

[image]